# Django model custom fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to build Django Model with basic fields and give user the ability to add custom fields from the UI. I thought I can add JSON field because I'm using PostgreSQL so that user can add any number of custom fields as save them as JSON.

I want to ask Is the above approach is correct? or Shall I create another table for custom fields? Please if there is another approach please guide me to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own widget with custom ui:

```
class JSONWidget(forms.Textarea):
    class Media:
        js = (
            'admin/json-widget/json-widget.js',
        )

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if 'class' in attrs:
            attrs['class'] += ' json-widget'
        else:
            attrs['class'] = 'json-widget'

        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        return mark_safe(u'<textarea%s>%s</textarea>' % (flatatt(final_attrs),
                                                         conditional_escape(force_unicode(value))))


class JSONField(models.TextField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['widget'] = JSONSWidget()
        return super(JSONField, self).formfield(**kwargs)


class SomeModel(model.Model):
    jsonfield = JSONField()
```